# Changing Android Implementation of Wifi Direct

Tags: android, wifi-direct, wifip2p

i recently got interested in the WifiDirect Technology and decided to create an Android app based on it. However, Android does not permit to have a multiple leaders in a P2pgroup, which makes joining groups not applicable.
My Question is, can we change this behaviour by changing the WifiDirectManager class? And if not what other options/alternatives do i have? can we achieve this on rooted devices?

Answer (score 2):

You can not change it. Basically with WiFi direct, device is either Group owner or Client, and there is no ways on being both same time. As well as there can be only one Group owner in each group. Which effectively makes it impossible to achieve what you are asking.

Anyway, maybe you should concentrate on designing a logic that works in your use case, and thus, you might want to explain what the actual issue is that you are facing.

Comment: what if my device is rooted ? can i change it ?

Comment: I generally work solely with vanilla software, thus can not be 100% certain, but would assume that it would not change the general behavior of this API.

Comment: @WalidKasem To rewrite Wi-Fi Direct would require rewriting the android interfaces to the wpa supplicant, the supplicant and probably the driver. What you want to do is essentially design a new protocol, which is not feasible.